# Using xsl:variable to set another variable using xsl:choose -> Invalid property

Tags: xslt, xsl-choose, xsl-variable

I'm trying to define some standard colours to use elsewhere in an XSLT, but the following gives an error:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="2.0">

    <xsl:variable name="rgbWeiss"       >rgb(255, 255, 255)</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="rgbHellBlauGrau">rgb(213, 235, 229)</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="rgbDunkelRot"   >rgb(128,   0,   0)</xsl:variable>
    :
    :
    <xsl:template match="row">

        <xsl:variable name="bgcolor">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when      test="position() mod 2 = 1">rgb(213, 235, 229)</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise                            >${rgbDunkelRot}</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <fo:table-row background-color="{$bgcolor}" xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-row-attr">
```

The error message is:

> Invalid property value encountered in background-color="${rgbDunkelRot}"

Unfortunately no useful information was provided for the location of the error.

The following works fine though:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="2.0">
    :
    :
    <xsl:template match="row">

        <xsl:variable name="bgcolor">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when      test="position() mod 2 = 1">rgb(213, 235, 229)</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise                            >rgb(128,   0,   0)</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <fo:table-row background-color="{$bgcolor}" xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-row-attr">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `${rgbDunkelRot}` is a meaningless text string. Use `<xsl:value-of select="$rgbDunkelRot"/>` to return the value of a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT 2 (you seem to use) I would simply do

```
<fo:table-row background-color="{if (position() mod 2 = 1) then $rgbHellBlauGrau else $rgbDunkelRot}" xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-row-attr">
```

or use that expression in the variable

```
<xsl:variable name="bgcolor" select="if (position() mod 2 = 1) then $rgbHellBlauGrau else $rgbDunkelRot"/>
```

Inside of the `xsl:choose/xsl:when/xsl:otherwise` you have the wrong syntax, you need `<xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$rgbDunkelRot"/></xsl:otherwise>` or move to XSLT 3 and `expand-text="yes"` with e.g. `<xsl:otherwise>{$rgbDunkelRot}</xsl:otherwise>`.

In "XSLT 4" currently experimented with in Saxon 10 PE or EE as an extension there is also a `select` attribute on `xsl:when` and `xsl:otherwise`: http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/xslt-syntax-extensions.html. So there you can write `<xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1" select="$rgbHellBlauGrau"/>`.